# How to add a column from a normal data frame to a spatial polygons data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, polygon, spatial

I am coding in R. I have a normal data frame named `A`, in this data frame (I mean `A`), there is a column named `Province`. I also have a spatial polygons data frame named `B`. I want to add the column `Province` to the spatial polygons data frame `B`.

`A` consists of the number of COVID-19 confirmed cases in a country.
`Province` is a column of the name of provinces of that country.
B includes the `shapefile` of administrative boundaries in that country.

I have tried to solve my problem but I could not! What I have coded are as follow:

`B<-A$Province`, but this is not what I want. I need the new B (after adding `Province`) as a new spatial polygons data frame.

My second try is this one:

```
B<-as.data.frame(B)
B<-cbind(B,Province=A$Provincea)
```

Like the first code, the above codes are not what I want, because I need the new `B` as a spatial polygons data frame (and not as a normal data frame).

To know more about `A` and `B`, I write the results of `dput(head(A))` and `dput(head(B))` in the following:

```
dput(head(A)):

structure(list(Province = c("EC", "FS", "GT", "KZ", "LM", "MP"
), Cases = c(2748L, 208L, 2993L, 1882L, 132L, 103L), Population = c(11.56, 
2.75, 12.27, 10.27, 5.4, 4.04)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

dput(head(B)):

structure(list(ID_0 = c("211", "211", "211", "211", "211", "211"
), ISO = c("ZAF", "ZAF", "ZAF", "ZAF", "ZAF", "ZAF"), NAME_0 = c("South Africa", 
"South Africa", "South Africa", "South Africa", "South Africa", 
"South Africa"), ID_1 = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), NAME_1 = c("Eastern Cape", 
"Free State", "Gauteng", "KwaZulu-Natal", "Limpopo", "Mpumalanga"
), TYPE_1 = c("Provinsie", "Provinsie", "Provinsie", "Provinsie", 
"Provinsie", "Provinsie"), ENGTYPE_1 = c("Province", "Province", 
"Province", "Province", "Province", "Province"), NL_NAME_1 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), VARNAME_1 = c("Oos-Kaap", "Orange Free State|Vrystaat", "Pretoria/Witwatersrand/Vaal", 
"Natal and Zululand", "Noordelike Provinsie|Northern Transvaal|Northern Province", 
"Eastern Transvaal")), row.names = 0:5, class = "data.frame")
```

Indeed, I want to add the column of `Province` of the normal data frame (`A`) to the spatial polygons data frame (`B`), then I want to merge `A` and `B`.

Could you please help me to solve the problem mentioned above?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example with code and data so that others can provide help.

Comment: @AndrewChisholm, I have edited and explained more about my problem. I hope it is now clear.

Comment: It looks to me that you're looking for a **join** or a **merge**. Let's say that **both** in `A` and `B` there's a column called "country". Then you can do: `library(data.table); setDT(A); setDT(B); newData = merge(A, B, by = "country")`. That way you'll have your data _joined_ by country

Comment: @Pavo, Yes, I finally want to merge normal data frame A and the spatial polygons data frame B. But A and B have no any same column. Because of this I want to first add the column a (from A) to B. But I do not know how to add!

Comment: Help us help you. Please paste the results of `dput(head(A))` and `dput(head(B))`. That was we can help

Comment: @Pavo, do you mean I run codes "dput(head(A))" and "dput(head(B))" in R, then I copy them from R and paste here?

Comment: not as a comment, but as an edit to your question

Comment: @PavoDive, I added the results of dput(head(A)) and dput(head(B)) as edition to my question.

Comment: your B dataset does not contain any "shapefile" column.

Comment: You need a common match keys in both sides. I.e. Your `A` data frame could have a column of unique `id` per row: `ndf$id <- rownames(ndf)`.  Then you can merge whit `B` in the same way has @PavoDive suggests: `merge(spdf, ndf, by.x = "ID_1", by.y = "id")`